# C: Number Guessing Game

Tags: c, random, srand

How do I define the number that I want the user to guess in a number guessing game?

There are two sample runs of the program that I need to follow, with the boldface being the user's input:

1. OK, I am thinking of a number. Try to guess it.

   Your guess? **50**
   Too high!
   Your guess? **12**
   Too low!
   Your guess? **112**
   Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 100.
   Try again. Your guess? **- 20**
   Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 100.
   Try again. Your guess? **23**

   ***CORRECT*****
2. Want to play again? **y**

   OK, I am thinking of a number. Try to guess it.
    Your guess?
   **85**
    Too high!
    Your guess? **12**
    Too low!
    Your guess? **57**

   ***CORRECT*****

I'm having trouble getting my script to output `***CORRECT*****` when I/the  user enter the number 23 in the 1st run. When I input 50, 12, 112, and -20, I get the correct response, but not with 23. After inputting 23, I get "Too low! Your guess?"
(I haven't tried the second run because I need to make sure I can get the 1st run to follow the sample.)

Here is a snippet of what I have:

```
void guessGame() 
{
int num = 23;
int guess = 0;
int count = 1;
count = 1;

srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
num = rand() % 100 +1;

printf("OK, I am thinking of a number. Try to guess it.\n");
printf("Your guess?\n");
scanf("%d",&guess);

while(guess != num && count != 6)
{
    if(guess > 100 || guess < 1)
    {
        printf("Illegal guess. Your guess must be between 1 and 100.\n");
        printf("Try again. Your guess?\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        count ++;
    }
    else if(guess > num)
    {
        printf("Too high! Your guess?\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        count ++;
    }
    else if(guess < num)
    {
        printf("Too low! Your guess?\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
        count ++;
    }
}
if (guess == num)
{
    printf("***CORRECT*****\n");
}
else 
    printf("Too many guesses\n");

printf("The number is %d\n\n", num);
}
```

Much help is appreciated. :)

Comment: The number to guess, `num`, is random; don't expect to reproduce the exact numbers from the sample.

Comment: `num = rand() % 100 +1;` changes the value from `23` to something else.

Comment: Do you set num = 23 and then assign a random value to num? Well then your script does exactly what it should and 23 is lower than the actual random number

Comment: Could I use num to output 'correct' if the user guesses in the correct range? For example, in the 1st run, the range could be 13-49. Or, is it strictly random?

Comment: It will be in the range `1 to 100`, because you are using `%100 + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN your function you initialize `num` as -

```
int num = 23;
```

but then you make it store any randomly generated number -

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
num = rand() % 100 +1;
```

which may not be `23` , it can be anything between `1 to 100`. Therefore , it shows output that is not expected .

If you want `num` to be `23` then remove then statement with `rand()` .

Comment: @Haris Edited that . Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you! I was worried I'd have to remove srand because the assignment requires I implement srand/rand(). I guess I was supposed to just use one or the other and not both...

Comment: @Anonymissy That depends on you . If you want random number hen use `rand()` , otherwise do manually assign it some value .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
srand(time(NULL));
rand();
int random_number = rand() % 100 + 1;
```